# Common Login for multiple Devise Login Modules in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

In my app I have different types of users/models which is configured via `devise gem` for registration process. Let me make you more clear.

- For **Doctor's** Login I have this path `http://localhost:3000/doctor/sign_in`
- For **Hospital's** Login I have this path `http://localhost:3000/hospital/sign_in`
- For **User's** Login I have this path `http://localhost:3000/user/sign_in`

As all these have their own database tables like `doctors`, `hospitals`, `users` in which all details are saved respectively.

Now what I want to know that Is that possible to have **Single Login page** and I login with registered `doctor's id` then it should redirect me to `Doctors` page, If I login with `hospital's id` then it should redirect me to `hospitals` page, so on.. Is that possible to achieve this? If yes then Can you please guide me in right direction what should I need to do?

**Note:** I am aware about managing `roles/user_types` but I can not do that as there are different informations needed for doctors, hospitals and Users..

Comment: after login, `if current_user.doctor? redirect_to doctor_path ...`

Comment: But while login If I want to check for correct credentials then
??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance)

```
class AuthUser < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Doctor < AuthUser; end
class Hospital < AuthUser; end
class User < AuthUser; end
```

and use devise for AuthUser.

About after sign in path you can custom `after_sign_in_path_for`. [Sample](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Comment: Bingo.. this is the same solution for what I am looking for.. 1+

Answer (score 1):

What I think that there should be only one for saving users, i.e., `users`. You can create a table named `user_types` which will contain user type names, i.e., doctor, hospital and user. User belongs to a User Type. It would look something like this

```
class User
  belongs_to :user_type
end

class UserType
  has_many :users
end
```

Then in application controller you can override devise's `after_sign_in_path_for` method and redirect user to the page based on their user type.

Hope this makes sense!

**or**

If this is not possible then you can add three radio buttons for Doctor, User and Hospital, user will have to select it's login type along with the credentials before signing. Handle the login in the back end based on the value of the selected radio button.

Comment: Yes that I thought before... But for each doctors, hospital they have their own different tasks and different pages... it is huge role and need all user's different details.. I hope you can understand

Comment: Okay, I got it. Check my edited answer, you can also do that.

Comment: So you mean that if Doctor's radio button is selected then it should check in doctors table.. Right?

Comment: Yes, if user selects a radio button other than its own, then show an error message to the user.

Comment: I like this approach too.. 1+